# How to make the 'supports resource sharing'to yes in scheduler control in xtrascheduler

Tags: c#, devexpress

hii

I ahve a scheduler control now i want to group the scheduler with respect to my dataset but it is showing that

support resource sharing =no
how i can make it to yes and how i ca group my scheduler depending on resource

help me plzz

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [How to: Enable Multi-resource Appointments](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument4217) topic in this regard.

I suggest that you find answers to your questions in [our search engine](http://search.devexpress.com/).  It knows even more than me :)